# Converting GMT to CST in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, timestamp, timezone

I am currently working with raw data that have timestamps in GMT and I want to convert them to CST. I am trying to use the cast function to change the timestamp, but it is not working- the times are not affected. Most of what I have read about timezones in postgresql assumes that the default timezone is UTC so I'm not sure if there is a different syntax needed for when the data I'm trying to convert is GMT. Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
WITH RECURSIVE "child" AS (
    SELECT "ConsultantDisplayID",
           "JoinDate",
           "ParentPersonDisplayID"
    FROM "public"."flight_export_consultant"
    WHERE "ConsultantDisplayID" = '4019'
UNION 
    SELECT c."ConsultantDisplayID", 
           CAST(c."JoinDate" at time zone 'america/chicago' as timestamp) as "JoinDate"
           c."ParentPersonDisplayID"
    FROM "public"."flight_export_consultant" AS c 
    JOIN "child" AS cd 
    ON c."ParentPersonDisplayID" = cd."ConsultantDisplayID"),
    
"sponsor" AS (
    SELECT 
        "child".*,
        c1."ConsultantDisplayID",
        Cast(c."JoinDate" at time zone 'america/chicago' as timestamp) as "Sponsor JoinDate"
    FROM "public"."flight_export_consultant" AS c1
    LEFT JOIN "child" 
    ON c1."ConsultantDisplayID" = "child"."ParentPersonDisplayID")  

SELECT * FROM "sponsor"
```

Comment: What is the type of the column that the timestamps are being stored in? What do you get when you ```select c."JoinDate" from "public"."flight_export_consultant"``` without any casting. FYI, Postgres does not assume the default timezone is UTC. Also for practical purposes GMT = UTC.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver I get dates that look like September 24, 2018, 4:01PM

Comment: What is the type of field/column that the timestamp is stored in?

Comment: Try this query to see if it helps you sort it out in your head:  `select "JoinDate", "JoinDate" at time zone 'UTC', "JoinDate" at time zone 'us/chicago' from flight_export_consultant where "JoinDate" is not null limit 10;`

Comment: @AdrianKlaver it says it is timestamp without time zone

Comment: @MikeOrganek I end up with the "JoinDate" and the "joinDate" at time zone america/chicago being the same, with the UTC results being 5 hours earlier- that should be the opposite right?. which makes me think that something else is wrong. But doing that query did allow me to visualize differently.

Comment: The problem is that the values in a `timestamp` column is assumed to be in your local timezone.  https://www.enterprisedb.com/postgres-tutorials/postgres-time-zone-explained  I am sure there should be a better way to do this since this will murder your performance, but I don't know what that could be so I use this as a workaround in this case:  `("JoinDate"::text||'z')::timestamptz at time zone 'utc'`.  This stuff is headache-inducing, and you need to be using `timestamptz` to avoid this class of problems.  I just noticed that it's just for display in your query.  I will put up an answer.

Comment: See my answer below for an alternate solution.  The overriding issue is that with ```timestamp``` you are assuming you know what  time zone the timestamp is in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that `JoinDate` is type `timestamp`, this should be a good workaround for your situation now that we have established that the values in `JoinDate` of type `timestamp` represent UTC/GMT timestamps, and your server is not in UTC/GMT.  The ideal solution is to use `timestamptz` columns.

The trick here is to cast `JoinDate` to `text`, append a `z` to it to make it UTC, and then cast it to `timestamptz`.  Once that is done, you can use `at time zone 'us/chicago'` to do the conversion for you.

```
WITH RECURSIVE "child" AS (
    SELECT "ConsultantDisplayID",
           "JoinDate",
           "ParentPersonDisplayID"
    FROM "public"."flight_export_consultant"
    WHERE "ConsultantDisplayID" = '4019'
UNION 
    SELECT c."ConsultantDisplayID", 
           "JoinDate",
           c."ParentPersonDisplayID"
    FROM "public"."flight_export_consultant" AS c 
    JOIN "child" AS cd 
    ON c."ParentPersonDisplayID" = cd."ConsultantDisplayID"),
    
"sponsor" AS (
    SELECT 
        "child".*,
        c1."ConsultantDisplayID",
        c."JoinDate" as "Sponsor JoinDate"
    FROM "public"."flight_export_consultant" AS c1
    LEFT JOIN "child" 
    ON c1."ConsultantDisplayID" = "child"."ParentPersonDisplayID")  

SELECT "ConsultantDisplayID", 
       ("JoinDate"::text||'z')::timestamptz at 'america/chicago' as "JoinDate",
       "ParentPersonDisplayID",
       "ConsultantDisplayID",
       ("JoinDate"::text||'z')::timestamptz at 'america/chicago' as "Sponsor JoinDate"
FROM "sponsor";
```

Comment: Does 'us/chicago' work for you? I get ```ERROR:  time zone "us/chicago" not recognized
```.  I have to use either ```'america/chicago'``` or  ```'us/central'```.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver I also had to use 'america/chicago'

Comment: @AdrianKlaver  It is not.  Thank you for catching my error.  I was using `us/central` while testing and then tried to convert it to Chicago in my answer in case OP has a strong sense of civic (or timezone) pride :)  I will correct my answer.

Answer (score 2):

As @Mike Organek pointed out a field of type `timestamp` assumes local time on entry. So first thing you need to establish is where the dates are being entered from and whether they are are actually being entered  as `GMT`. For the moment assuming they are you could do the following:

```
select 'September 24, 2018, 4:01PM'::timestamp at time zone 'utc' at time zone 'america/chicago';
      timezone       
---------------------
 09/24/2018 11:01:00

-- Or if you want to stick to GMT

select 'September 24, 2018, 4:01PM'::timestamp at time zone 'gmt' at time zone 'america/chicago';
      timezone       
---------------------
 09/24/2018 11:01:00
```

Basically you are 'anchoring' the timestamp at `UTC/GMT` and then converting to `'america/chicago'`. In other words replicating what a `timestamptz` field does.